# How to define extern type?

Tags: rust, ffi

I have some c functions with a struct pointer argument.

```
extern "C" {
    fn InitSomeStruct() -> *SomeStruct;
    fn SomeFunction(v: *SomeStruct);
    fn DestroySomeStruct(v: *SomeStruct);
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let s = InitSomeStruct();
        SomeFunction(s);
        DestroySomeStruct(s);
    }
}
```

The implementation of SomeStruct is unknown.
How to declare and use external struct like SomeStruct from the rust code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is to use an empty enum for opaque FFI types, that is:

```
enum SomeStruct {}
```

An empty struct like `struct SomeStruct;` is also used sometimes.